# Duplicating array contents in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Say I have an array X=[1,2,3,4,5] and I want to duplicate the array twice in the following format:

[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]

What would be the easiest option?

Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [kron](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html) command does exactly what you need.

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5];
kron(X, [1 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using matrix multiplication:

```
Y = [1; 1] * X;
Y = Y(:)';
```

You can do it in one line with RESHAPE function:

```
Y = reshape([1; 1] * X,1,[]);
```

Alternatively you can use REPMAT function:

```
Y = reshape(repmat(X,2,1), 1,[]);
```